# How to write below code to functional way using java 8

Tags: lambda, java-8, functional-programming

I am new to lambda expressions and functional programming.
I wrote below code snippet using java 8.

```
     List<Employee> myList = new ArrayList<>();
     Map<String, List<Integer>> mapOf = new HashMap<>();
     mapOf.put("key1", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));

     mapOf.put("key2", Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6));
     mapOf.put("key3", Arrays.asList(7, 8));

     mapOf.forEach((k ,v) -> {
         Employee emp = new Employee();
         v.stream().forEach(o ->{
             emp.setFirstName("John Doe");
             myList.add(emp);
             System.out.println("Posting Data for :: " + k + " :: " + o);
         });
     });
```

Expected output

```
Posting Data for :: key1 :: 1
Posting Data for :: key1 :: 2
Posting Data for :: key1 :: 3
Posting Data for :: key2 :: 4
Posting Data for :: key2 :: 5
Posting Data for :: key2 :: 6
Posting Data for :: key3 :: 7
Posting Data for :: key3 :: 8
```

The above code is working as expected, but it's a *spaghetti* *code*.
I read many articles stating that we should not use **{** **}** inside lambda expressions as it makes code difficult to understand. 

So, now I am trying to convert it into the *Functional* way.
Please help.

Comment: `mapOf.forEach((k ,v) ->  v.forEach(o ->System.out.println("Posting Data for :: " + k + " :: " + o)));`

Comment: if you need just values `mapOf.forEach((k ,v) -> v.forEach(System.out::println));`

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I have updated the code and trying to convert this code, Apologies folk .

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: @nullpointer i am trying to write above code in functional way.

Comment: @mayankbisht the question is, but what are you trying to achieve in the code in question/

Comment: @nullpointer: oh I am iterating map and performing the operation on the value of each element present in the list corresponding to it's key. For more clarity, I have updated the above code with expected output.

Comment: @mayankbisht but them the `myList` and `Employee` object are currently useless in the code. Or for each `(key,value)` in the map, do you want to construct the same obejct and keep adding to the list? Which one could have done so for the size of the `Map` itself as well.

Comment: @nullpointer: yes, i need that piece of code as well, because i am using that list somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

this is probably what you want

```
ArrayList<Employee> myL = mapOf.entrySet()
        .stream()
            .map(en ->
                  en.getValue().stream()
                    .map(l ->{
                        Employee emp = new Employee();
                        emp.setFirstName("John Doe");
                        System.out.println("Posting Data for :: " + en.getKey() + " :: " + l);
                        return emp;
                    }).collect(Collectors.toList())
                )
            .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::addAll,ArrayList::addAll);
```